# Error "Base name not defined" when converting a pandas data frame into a data frame dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a large pandas dataframe df and I need to trasform it into Dask data.frame dd. With:

```
 dd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=n)
```

Python returns the error: Base 'name' not defined. why?

Comment: Can you please supply some sample data?

Comment: I noticed that it is independent of the dataset. It seems like a global python mistake.

Comment: This is highly unlikely. Just tested it with one of mine dataframes and it worked without a problem.

Comment: I have tested on other datasets and it returns the same error.

Comment: What dask version are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that df has data? can you elaborate your post with an example?